# how to use thin-specific cli options in rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, command-line-interface, thin

I'm using `thin` and launch it through `rails server thin`. (If I launch thin separately I have 2 logs (rails and thin log) and no stacktraces in some cases.) If I try to launch it with the option `-S /var/tmp/thin/thin.sock` rails server complains that it's not a valid option.

Answer (score 0):

try switching to thin command:

```
thin -S=/var/tmp/thin/thin.sock
```